# How to prevent NullPointerException on substr()?

Tags: java, string

I have several `substr()` calls in my application. Is there any common library, eg by `apache`, that provides a substring utility which does not throw NPE if the value is null, but then just returns an empty string?

I know I could write it like this, but maybe there is already such in implementation?

```
public static String substr(String value, int idx) {
   return value != null ? value.substr(idx) : "";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the apache commons [StringUtils.substring](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substring%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29)

An apache commons lang equivalent to your code is

```
StringUtils.defaultString(StringUtils.substring(value, idx));
```

Comment: cant't we already use
StringUtils.substring(value, idx)
?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you need a library for that. Just check against null and the length to avoid exceptions.

```
public static String substr(String value, int idx) {

    if (value == null || value.isEmpty() || idx > value.length()) return "";

    return value.substr(idx);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the length to avoid an exceptiom

```
public static String substr(int idx) {
    if(value==null||idx>value.length){
        return "";                // Exception avoided 
    } 
    return value.substr(idx) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already coded it, and by definition you cannot make a call on a null object, so the library would do something like what you have written.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway when you know what to do also it is quite simple.
You can put an utility class in your app with substr static method. Search and replace all the calls in the App with the one in utility class.